# Type checking object parameter in function using other parameter as its key

Tags: typescript, function, parameters, typechecking

I want to create a function that takes in three parameters: an object, a key on the object, and a new value. I want the function to be able to access a value using the key parameter, perform some operation based on that data, and then set the property to the new value.

This was the initial approach I took:

```
function someOperation(obj: object, key: keyof obj, newValue: typeof obj[key])
```

```
const obj = { a: 'hello', b: 2 };

// TypeScript should show an error here if the third parameter is not a string
someOperation(obj, 'a', 'goodbye');
console.log(obj); // should be { a: 'goodbye', b: 2 }
```

Unfortunately, I get some undescriptive errors where I specify the type of `newValue`. I could just set its type to `any` to fix the errors, but I really want to have stronger type checking. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could solve this problem? Perhaps there are different ways to approach this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zixiCat's solution is perfectly valid and works. But it may seem far-fetched and is difficult to debug the error messages like

```
Argument of type '["a", "1"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TParams<{ a: number; b: string; }>'.
  Type '["a", "1"]' is not assignable to type '["a", number]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

There is more elegant and simple solution possible with "more-friendly" errors.

```js
function someOperation<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  value: T[K]
) {
  //
}

const test = { a: 1, b: '1' };

someOperation(test, 'a', 1); // OK
someOperation(test, 'b', '1'); // OK
someOperation(test, 'a', '1'); // Error
someOperation(test, 'c', '1'); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYHkAOGBOAhrAgDwAqiGAHlBmACbKIDeAvgDSIDSVt9TRAGsMATzjBE5AHwAKAFCJEcAEYArAFxSOi4WK3cdSgG6EANiAxbyAbW4BdeQEpWugPRv5befIgJkUIh0AYgAvKyIhFoAjFwqWgDk0QmIbADcPqiYuATE8GCywVBcCYQJXNFOaYgeiFjc8lnYeEQkBUUlKuWISQlVNW51DU05rfmFGAElZSXJ-bUAovj4cPiN6M25bRNTPRDdvfODSytrQA)

Answer (score 2):

The core idea is [union-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and using Arr to wrap them like that:

```
type paramsArr = [ObjType, 'a', number] | [ObjType, 'b', string]
```

And then you can try this one:

```
type TParamsMap<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: [P, T[P]] // [key, newValue];
};


type TParams<T> = TParamsMap<T>[keyof TParamsMap<T>]

function someOperation<T>(obj: T, ...rest: TParams<T>) {
  obj[rest[0]] = rest[1];
}

const test = { a: 1, b: '1' };

someOperation( test, 'a', 1); // OK
someOperation( test, 'b', '1'); // OK
someOperation( test, 'a', '1'); // Error
someOperation( test, 'c', '1'); // Error
```

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question. The keys on the object are not all the same type, so, for example, if the object contains both numbers and strings, then the function will allow `newValue` to be either type. Refer to my updated question for more information.

Comment: @flamesdev, the code works if it contains different typed keys. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYHkAOGBOAhrAgDwAqiGAHlBmACbKIDeAvgHwAUAUIonABGAKwBcicgBo+iANYYAnuPkK4wCdP5gMAdwBqhADYgM48gG0VaiQF0eASlYyA9M55sePCAmRQBIxABeVkRCcQBGSURBcQByQkEIWMQ2AG4eVExcAmJ4MC4hYSj42KiAZnt0jPRsPCISfMLiwVLEACZ7IA)

Comment: @Shivam Singla: When the key is 'b', this function someOperation(obj, 'b', 2) did not show error, 2 should be string, so I rejected your edit and update my new answer that meets its requirement.

Comment: @zixiCat Thank you for your response; your code works perfectly. Your solution is very interesting; I never knew you could do something like that.

Comment: @zixiCat I was aware of that. OP had written, "newValue to be either type" in the comment. So I didn't took the constraint into account. That's why the example `someOperation(obj, 'b', 2)`

Comment: @ShivamSingla I'm sorry about that, haha. I suppose my comment to clarify my question was also ambiguous. When I said "the function" in my previous comment, I was referring to the one in zixiCat's answer.

Comment: @flamesdev no worries. The problem is solved finally.